# This course wasn't supposed to be hard

Tags: meaning

Someone said this course wasn't supposed to be hard. What meaning is this sentence. Did he think this course was difficult or easy or it only can be know based on the tone?

Answer (score 0):

It’s not the tone that tells you, but the context:

> 1. I can’t believe how much I’ve been struggling with Geology 101. This course wasn’t supposed to be hard.
> 2. Alice told me she took Geology 101 last semester. This course wasn’t supposed to be hard. She said she breezed right through it.

In context 1, the course is harder than expected. In context 2, the course is expected to be easy (not hard).

Answer (score 0):

This sentence could be used to describe how a class is meeting an earlier expectation *or* how it is failing to meet that expectation.

> “I’m surprised at how difficult these assignments are. **This course wasn’t supposed to be hard. **”

In this first example, the speaker is explaining that the course is hard even though they expected it to be easy.

> “I haven’t been challenged by the assignments this semester, but that’s fine. **This course wasn’t supposed to be hard. **”

In the second example, the speaker is explaining that they did not expect the course to be hard, and indeed it was not.

If no additional context is available, then you must rely on tone as you suggested. If the sentence is spoken with an exasperated or despairing tone, you can assume the meaning to be closer to the first example above. If the tone is satisfied or matter-of-fact, the speaker likely intends a meaning more like the second example.